# how to hide the slider selector in firefox?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, node-sass

[image]

in order to hide white circle selector I've added the below mentioned styling but it is not working.

```
input[type="range"]::-moz-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
}
```

I tried to use `-moz-range-thumb` instead of `-moz-slider-thumb` but still no luck.

P.S. - I'm using node-sass and below styling works fine in chromium based browser

```
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      height: 16px;
      width: 16px;
    }
```

Comment: you try display: none? or opacity: 0 ?

Comment: @IWI yes, but those didn't wrok

Comment: Could you please share your HTML as well? This enables us to accurately reproduce your problem in our answers, rather than guessing at what you've (maybe) done; also it saves us the time taken to create the code from our assumptions.

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica it's a react app. I'll upload it to github and update the question with the github link

Comment: @Arka: no, please don't. Run the script, and look at the resulting generated page (in the DOM of the app, or page, you should see the resulting DOM, there is unlikely to be any React in there at that point).

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica should I share the entire resulting HTML of the page ?

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica this is my app https://ibb.co/Kx4qCZ3

Comment: Take a read of the "*[mcve]*" guidelines :) we only need enough to recreate the problem you're facing. Admittedly this is a React app, but the problem seems like it's CSS related rather than React based?